# Visual Studio 2012 Git Tools

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2012

I created a repository (private one) on github. I downloaded the Visual Studio tools for git. Then, I created a project on my laptop. I added the same to source control (git). I made my first commit to local repo (branch master) and then I decided to push this branch to github repository.

The first problem was that I was unable to publish branch named "master" because the same branch exists on remote repo. I created a new branch with a different name and published it. But I was unhappy with two branches, I needed only one. But the real problem appeared then. My roommate decided to work on the same project. First, he cloned the repository.

But only one file - readme from remote branch master copied! After that, he created a project of the same type and published new branch to same remote repo (third one!).

Unfortunately, we were unable to pull remote my branch because we couldn't find it in the command explorer.

Comment: You might want to read the definitive git guide for beginners (here on SO)

Comment: And don't use jntegrated tools for learning. Use the Git Bash. No beginner guide tells you how to start with git with the VS2012 tools. They're all console based (which is the only reasonable way to use git anyways)